# How to disable scroll of body while scrolling on a fixed div without hiding scroll bar of body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I prevent scrolling of body when i scroll on a fixed div. I tried overflow:hidden of body, it works perfectly except that the page is shaking when the scroll bar is removed. is there a way to keep scroll bar and prevent scrolling?

Comment: Would be nice if you'd provided your code (ideally with a link to jsfiddle or similar).

Comment: do you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('mousewheel',".dropdown-menu-rightt", function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
       $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop()-e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY);
      //prevent page fom scrollin
      return false;
   });
   });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4k275c7p/8/) for a simple body with 2 p elements and a div. as you can see, if you're scrolling inside the div, the body won't scroll anyway. there's no need to set overflow to hidden. just make sure the div itself has overflow-y set to scroll. css on the div below. no css on the body or javascript needed

```
.theDiv{
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```